# Simple folder/file lock handler

Tags: python-3.x, locking

I have two python scripts (or one bash script + one python script) which are working independently from another, one script puts data into a folder, the other one reads from it.

Since I don't want to accidentally read from the folder at the same time it's updated, I created this simple folder lock using a dummy file.

In the bash script a similar thing is done, by checking whether that lock.file exists, and if not create it, put the current PID into it, and after it's done delete it.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

class SimpleFolderLock():
    def __init__(self, folder_path, time_out=5):
        self._folder_to_lock = folder_path
        self._lock_file_path = os.path.join(self._folder_to_lock, "folder.lock")
        self._lock_time_out = time_out
        
    def __enter__(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        while os.path.exists(self._lock_file_path):
            LOGGER.debug(f"Waiting for {self._lock_file_path} to clear")
            time.sleep(5)
            if (time.time() - start_time) > self._lock_time_out:
                LOGGER.error(
                    f"Time-out for waiting for {self._lock_file_path} to clear")
                raise TimeoutError(f"Can't lock {self._folder_to_lock} after {self._lock_time_out} seconds")
    
        LOGGER.debug(f"Locking with {self._lock_file_path}")
        with open(self._lock_file_path, "w") as fn:
            fn.write(str(os.getpid()))
            
        return self._lock_file_path
    
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        try:
            LOGGER.debug(f"Clearing {self._lock_file_path}")
            os.remove(self._lock_file_path)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            LOGGER.error(f"File {self._lock_file_path} already got deleted")
```

And for a simple test:

```
# Just some dummy logging configuration
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
test_folder = "/tmp/test_dir/"
os.makedirs(test_folder, exist_ok=True)
with SimpleFolderLock(test_folder) as lock:
    lock_path = lock
    LOGGER.info(f"Locked with {lock_path}")
    assert os.path.exists(lock_path)
    fiddle_around_in_folder(test_folder)

    
assert not os.path.exists(lock_path)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a race condition here:

```
while os.path.exists(self._lock_file_path):
...
with open(self._lock_file_path, "w") as fn:
```

The file could have been created by the other process in between. You need to check file existence and create the file in one operation.

Since python 3.3 there is a special `open` mode `x` for this use case:

> open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists

For example:

```
while (time.time() - start_time) < self._lock_time_out:
    try:
        with open(self._lock_file_path, "x") as fn:
            fn.write(str(os.getpid()))
    except FileExistsError:
        time.sleep(5)
```